# Is there a Perl module that can automate ollydbg?

Tags: perl, debugging, ollydbg

Is there a CPAN module that can automate the famous [ollydbg debugger](http://www.ollydbg.de/)?
If yes, could someone provide such module and some tutorials/documentaitons/example about it?

Comment: Sorry for the nit pick, but "famous"? I've never heard of it and I presume that applies to quite a few others, too. Could you add a link?

Comment: see this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OllyDbg

Answer (score 6):

Googling brings up this:

- http://www.openrce.org/downloads/details/220/OllyPerl

Note that it's from 2005 and provides this description:

> Perl scripting for the OllyDbg API, Alpha-quality code, use at your own risk. Requires ActivePerl.
>
> Also included in package is wavediff.pl, a PoC implementation of binary difference analysis via phase cancellation.

YMMV but the author still [blogs](http://www.joestewart.org/) & [twitters](http://twitter.com/joestewart71).